# Squelch Bash imports in Jenkins

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, sh

We have a number of bash scripts running on our Jenkins server for handling our CI/CD tasks. In these tasks, we import other bash scripts or use the bash login shell for certain commands.

As part of this, we get a ton of useless output in our console. For example, with the login shell, we get tons of reporting of Ruby Version Manage initializing for the shell. Eg:

```
09:19:51  + for __zsh_like_cd_hook in chpwd "${chpwd_functions[@]}"
09:19:51  + typeset -f __rvm_cd_functions_set
09:19:51  + __rvm_cd_functions_set
09:19:51  + __rvm_do_with_env_before
09:19:51  + [[ -n '' ]]
09:19:51  + [[ -n /usr/local/rvm ]]
09:19:51  + source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/initialize
09:19:51  ++ [[ -n 5.0.17(1)-release ]]
09:19:51  ++ shopt -s extglob
09:19:51  ++ ((  0 == 1  ))
09:19:51  ++ export __rvm_env_loaded
09:19:51  ++ : __rvm_env_loaded:0:
09:19:51  ++ : __rvm_env_loaded:1:
09:19:51  ++ [[ -z '' ]]
09:19:51  ++ typeset -f __rvm_cleanse_variables
09:19:51  ++ __rvm_cleanse_variables
09:19:51  ++ __rvm_unset_ruby_variables
09:19:51  ++ unset rvm_env_string rvm_ruby_string rvm_ruby_strings rvm_ruby_binary rvm_ruby_gem_home rvm_ruby_gem_path rvm_ruby_home rvm_ruby_interpreter rvm_ruby_irbrc rvm_ruby_log_path rvm_ruby_major_version rvm_ruby_minor_version rvm_ruby_package_name rvm_ruby_patch_level rvm_ruby_release_version rvm_ruby_repo_url rvm_ruby_repo_branch rvm_ruby_revision rvm_ruby_selected_flag rvm_ruby_tag rvm_ruby_version rvm_head_flag rvm_ruby_package_file rvm_ruby_configure rvm_ruby_name rvm_ruby_url rvm_ruby_global_gems_path rvm_ruby_args rvm_ruby_name rvm_llvm_flag rvm_ruby_repo_tag
09:19:51  ++ __rvm_load_rvmrc
09:19:51  ++ typeset _file
09:19:51  ++ typeset -a rvm_rvmrc_files
09:19:51  ++ ((  0 == 1  ))
09:19:51  ++ [[ -n '' ]]
09:19:51  +++ umask
09:19:51  ++ export rvm_stored_umask=0022
09:19:51  ++ rvm_stored_umask=0022
09:19:51  ++ rvm_rvmrc_files=("/etc/rvmrc" "$HOME/.rvmrc")
09:19:51  ++ [[ -n /usr/local ]]
09:19:51  ++ [[ /var/lib/jenkins/.rvmrc -ef /usr/local/.rvmrc ]]
09:19:51  ++ rvm_rvmrc_files+=("${rvm_prefix}/.rvmrc")
09:19:51  ++ for _file in "${rvm_rvmrc_files[@]}"
09:19:51  ++ [[ -s /etc/rvmrc ]]
09:19:51  ++ __rvm_grep '^\s*rvm .*$' /etc/rvmrc
...
```

Is there any way to silence this information so we have cleaner console output?

Comment: For each script called, redirect the stderr to a separate log file (on per script basis? or to /dev/null ).  Normal output (stdout) would be unaffected.  You have to ensure that what normally is automatically directed to stderr by individual commands is correctly redirected to stdout, if visibility of that output is desired.

Answer (score 0):

I went through all the scripts that I could in our Infrastructure repository again and found a common theme among them: they all used `set -x` in their scripts.

I looked at the documentation for Bash and found:

```
-x
Print a trace of simple commands, for commands, case commands, select commands, and arithmetic for commands and their arguments or associated word lists after they are expanded and before they are executed. The value of the PS4 variable is expanded and the resultant value is printed before the command and its expanded arguments.
```

Removing `set -x` in the scripts significantly reduced the noise being printed to the console.